# Data View: Only count the JobID without TestSend

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, data-views

Is there a way to count with SQL the sents excluding the jobid from test sent?

My sintax below:

```
SELECT 
DATEPART(yyyy,GETDATE()) AS [Year],
'BU1' AS [Business Unit],
COUNT(*) AS JobID,
DATEPART(m,PickupTime) AS [Month]
FROM
_Job
WHERE
AccountID = '100000001'
AND DATEPART(m, PickupTime) = DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate()))
AND DATEPART(yyyy, PickupTime) = DATEPART(yyyy, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate()))
GROUP BY
DATEPART(m,PickupTime)
```

Comment: Have you tried filtering by JobType or TestEmailAddr?

Comment: No :/ How could i do this with JobType?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this by adding the following condition to your query:

```
WHERE TestEmailAddr = ''
```

TestEmailAddr column will only be populated for emails which were sent as test sends, so if you filter them out, you will get all the remaining sends.

You also need to check your query syntax, as you are trying to query a column which is not part of the _Job data view: `BU1`

A list of all _Job columns can be found here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_job.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=nullrigin=null

Answer (score 6):

These test sends also have a `Category` of `Test Send Emails` so you could have your query have the following in the where clause:

`where category != 'Test Send Emails'`

Comment: I meant that you should also add that `SupressTracking` can be used here too and since it's a boolean, it should be more efficient that checking for a string. I'm going to delete my question now, because at least this information is recorded in my comment ;)